# Laravel 5: Validate if field value exists if data source is not MYSQL but Repository

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am working on REST API with add/update/delete methods.

In Controller, In Update action i have to check if id passed exists, I know i can use **Laravel validator exists:table,column** , but i am using Repository inside controller

```
public function __construct(BookRepositoryInterface $bookRepository, Validator $validator)
{
    $this->bookRepository = $bookRepository;
    $this->validator = $validator;
}
```

Repository source can be different than mysql database. Laravel validator 'exists' will not work in every case.

This is the code for updating book by an id.

```
public function update($id)
{
    $params = Input::only('title', 'author');

    $params['id'] = $id;

    $rules = array(
        'id' => 'required',
        'author' => 'required',
        'title' => 'required'

    );

    $validator = $this->validator->make($params, $rules);

     ...........
}
```

What is best way to check if id exists in book repository during update?

Comment: Make a custom validation rule that uses your repository to validate if the record exists.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for that, is to have the create method on the Repository, and run the validation inside the repository.
In that case, the validation implementation will be Repository dependent.

Comment: I think validation shouldn't be done inside repository.

Comment: Why you think so, this is the best way to ensure the validation is Repository dependent.

Comment: Validation should be done on an upper level like a Service ( it has the repository object)

Comment: Laravel Spark has a similar implementation. The Contract is calling an Interaction, and the interaction has the validation implementation.